# Unable to access value using Property decorator in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-decorator, javascript-decorators

I am writing a Vanilla Typescript Program, as shown below

```
class DecoratorClass{
  @HelloWorld
  public property1:string="Siddu Rocks"
}
function HelloWorld(target:any,propertyName:string){
    console.log("The Class Target and prop names are:"+target[propertyName] + "," + 
                  propertyName)
}
```

I am getting the output as *The Class Target and prop names are:undefined,property1*
instead of *The Class Target and prop names are: Siddu Rocks,property1*

Why I am getting the property value as undefined, Is there anything I am missing here? I tried checking multiple blogs but no avail

Kindly help me

Answer (score 1):

A common misconception: `target` in the decorator is actually *not* an instance of the class, [but the class prototype itself](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#property-decorators).

Also, the transpiled JavaScript actually looks something like this (even when using the ESNext target):

```js
class DecoratorClass {
    constructor() {
        this.property1 = "Siddu Rocks";
    }
}
```

which is why when you attempt to log `target[propertyName]`, gives you `undefined`. It's simply not declared on the class, but rather set when you create an instance of the class.

From the link above, there is also this note:

> A Property Descriptor is not provided as an argument to a property decorator due to how property decorators are initialized in TypeScript. This is because there is currently no mechanism to describe an instance property when defining members of a prototype, and no way to observe or modify the initializer for a property. The return value is ignored too. As such, a property decorator can only be used to observe that a property of a specific name has been declared for a class.

Essentially, class decorators can only be used to modify the property (replace with getters/setters, observe changes to it, validate on change, etc).

Comment: So I cannot access the value in the property1? with Property Decorator? I was referring to this link betterprogramming.pub/…

Comment: No, you can't. That also doesn't make sense. How do you access the value before it's defined?

Comment: My usecase here is I want to add NotNull Decorator, to make sure that the value is initialized? How can I do that?

Comment: Is the decorator supposed to check it at runtime? Decorators cannot validate things at compile time. You might want to check if there is already a question on Stack Overflow for that, and if it isn't feel free to ask another one.

Comment: So essentially I can use Class Decorators for getting the values of the properties in the runtime? to do any validation?

Comment: You wouldn't get the value of the property. Instead you would replace it with a getter and setter. In the setter you can add validation. Like I said, you might want to find how to do it somewhere else, or ask another question about it.

Comment: @Siddarth No I meant ask another question as in *post* another question, as it could be more helpful to future users (and also make the entire post easier to follow).

Comment: I love your question. I have also the same query. When property decorator is placed on an instance member (as opposed to static member), why is this decorator given a prototype?  And the funny thing is, when placed on a static member, it is NOT given a prototype.

Comment: @NickWills Decorators usually only modify their target, so a decorator for an instance member would get the prototype, to modify the instance field or method. Likewise, decorators for static members get the class itself, to modify the static field or method.

Comment: @vr.  Hi. Thanks for the reply. But i thought instance field is not found in the prototype.  So getting the prototype to modify the instance field seem weird to me. Whatever field set in the prototype, is shared by all the instances, in which case it is not considered "instance field" .   Do correct me, if my understanding is wrong. Thanks

Comment: @NickWills I say "instance field" as in "all instances share this field", regardless of whether or not the field is declared on the instance itself or the prototype.

Answer (score 0):

Property decorators are modifying the class not the instance. So property1 is not set at the time `HelloWorld` is called.

Comment: So I cannot access the value in the property1? with Property Decorator? I was referring to this link https://betterprogramming.pub/an-introduction-to-typescript-property-decorators-1c9db23b6ca1#:~:text=With%20a%20property%20decorator%2C%20you%20can%20change%20the,property%20decorator%3A%20How%20To%20Create%20a%20Property%20Decorator

Answer (score -1):

```
function Min(limit:number){
return (target:Object,propertyKey:string) => {
    let value:string;
    console.log("Orignal Value ",target[propertyKey]); // undefined
    console.log("Original Value ", this[propertyKey]); //undefined
    const getter = function() {
        return value;
    }
    Object.defineProperty(target,propertyKey,{
        get:getter,
        set:function(newVal:string){
            if (newVal.length < limit) {
                let error:ValidationError = {
                    type: propertyKey,
                    message:`Your password must be greater than ${limit}`
                };
                let errors = this["errors"];
                console.log("ERRORS: ",errors);
                // Here I wanted to update the errors field, and I accessed it using this["errors"]. This will get all the errors and push the new error.
                errors.push(error);
                Object.defineProperty(target,"errors",{
                    value:errors
                })
            }else{
                value = newVal
            }
        }
    })
 }
}



type ValidationError = {
    type: string,
    message: string
}

class User {
    errors:ValidationError[] = [];
    @Min(8)
    password:string;

    @Min(7)
    username:string;
    constructor(password:string,username:string) {
        this.password = password;
        this.username = username;
    }
}

const user = new User("12345","fahad");
console.log(user.errors);
```

My output is following:

```
Orignal Value  undefined
Orignal Value  undefined
ERRORS:  []
ERRORS:  [
  { type: 'password', message: 'Your password must be greater than 8' }
]
[
  { type: 'password', message: 'Your password must be greater than 8' },
  { type: 'username', message: 'Your password must be greater than 7' }
]
```